# Message of the day system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got some code that is loaded on my footer via jquery (So that every page visited has the code on its page)

This code is meant to check a database and, if any responses, send a bootstrap modal to the client. When the modal is sent, the row is deleted from the database. Each user has their own row in the database when an update happens.

The footer code is reloaded every 10 seconds to check if there are any updates to the relative table.

This works, except even after the row is deleted, PHP seems to execute code inside my if blocks that shouldn't be executeted, as it is causing the modal to close or pile up on top of eachother, forcing the client to reload their page to continue browsing.

So lets say a client loads the index page, and they have a pending message waiting for them.
The modal is sent for the user to close manually. If the user waits more than 10 seconds, the modal will close itself but the backdrop will remain, making it so the user cannot click anything until the page is reloaded. If the user waits another 10 seconds, another backdrop is added, darkening the screen. This goes on and on until the screen is completely black or the client reloads the page.

The code that opens the modal is inside of 2 if blocks basically stating that it should not be executed.

Here is my reloading code:

```
<?

    include("dbConnect.php");

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Message,uniqueID from sendMessage WHERE UserID='".$_GET['userID']."';";

    $ret = $db->query($sql);

    $loop = 0;

    $messages = array();

    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }

    while($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){

        $loop++;

        array_push($messages,array("uniqueID" => $row['uniqueID'], "Message" => $row['Message']));

    }


    if($loop != 0) {
        if(!empty($messages)) {

            ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                    $('#memberModal').modal('show');
                });
            </script>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="memberModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Message from Administrators</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <?
                            foreach($messages as $v) {
                                echo $v['Message'];
                                if($loop > 1) {
                                    echo "<br><br>";
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?

            foreach($messages as $v) {
                    $sql2 = "DELETE from sendMessage where uniqueID='".$v['uniqueID']."';";
                    $ret2 = $db->exec($sql2);
            }


        }
    }

    ?>
```

As far as I can tell, all the imports are correct (Otherwise the modal wouldn't work at all, right?)

Here is the jquery in my footer:

```
            <div id="links"></div>
            <script>
                function loadlink(){
                    $('#links').load('templates/sendMessage.php?userID=<?=$userInfo['uniqueid'];?>',function () {});
                }

                loadlink(); // This will run on page load
                setInterval(function(){
                    loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
                }, 10000);
            </script>
```

**--edit--**

I suspect my issue is because the div is reloaded again while the modal is open, therefore breaking it because it is erasing the code the modal is in. I'm not sure how to combat this.

Comment: Is the DELETE statement successfully removing the rows? If so, have you verified that the second and later calls to sendMessage.php are not using cached responses? GET requests are often cached by browsers unless your server is configured to prevent such behavior.

Comment: @Steve It is removing the rows, yes. Did you read my edit? Is that a possibility? How can I check if its using a cached response?

Comment: Use the network tab in Chrome to see if it's a cached response, or select the "disable cache" checkbox in the network tab to force un-cached requests to test

Answer (score 0):

The code is not complete, but from what I can tell your ajax script should only send the content of the modal, not the whole modal, `append()` it in (or use `html()` if you want to remove the previous messages) `<div class="modal-body">` and then show the modal. Now you are inserting the whole modal code inside the modal and get a babushka effect.

-- EDIT --

In your php script, return only the messages, not the modal html:

```
[...]
if($loop != 0) {
    if(!empty($messages)) {
        foreach($messages as $v) {
            echo $v['Message'];
            if($loop > 1) {
                echo "<br><br>";
            }
        }
[...]
```

The in the footer

```
   <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="memberModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="memberModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Message from Administrators</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                       // mesages will be inserted here
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            function loadlink(){
                $('.modal-body').load('templates/sendMessage.php?userID=<?=$userInfo['uniqueid'];?>',function () {
                     // maybe add a condition to see if nothing is returned
                     // and not show it
                     $('#memberModal').modal('show');
                });
            }

            loadlink(); // This will run on page load
            setInterval(function(){
                loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
            }, 10000);
        </script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean the code is not complete? I've given you every piece of code that is relevant.

Comment: I mean the html. But anyway, apart from this, did you try the solution?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do this